# What does GGX stand for?

Tags: rendering, specular, microfacet, distribution

Many render engines implement the microfacet model for rendering surfaces that are rough, metallic, and/or transparent, a concept first published in "[A Reflectance Model for Computer Graphics](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/357290.357293)" This model implies that surfaces comprise a large number of microfacets, each with a random slope. The slopes of all the microfacets on a surface can be categorized with a facet slope distribution function.

Some render engines like EEVEE and Cycles allow users to select such function (called a "light scattering distribution function" in Blender), and the default is **GGX**.

[image: Blender nodes with GGX]

GGX is presented in the paper "[Microfacet Models for Refraction through Rough Surfaces](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/2383847.2383874)."

In this paper's introduction:

> We also introduce a new microfacet distribution, which we call GGX...

...but they never explain *why* they call it GGX.

Perhaps it's mentioned somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to E. Heitz ([Sampling the GGX Distribution of Visible Normals](https://jcgt.org/published/0007/04/01/paper.pdf)) it stands for "ground glass unknown". I am not sure what the word unknown means though.

By the way, it is equivalent to [Trowbridge-Reitz distribution](https://pharr.org/matt/blog/images/average-irregularity-representation-of-a-rough-surface-for-ray-reflection.pdf), introduced much earlier.